# Centering div without it to jump to top?

Tags: css

When I am trying to center div like

```
.div {
    display: block;
    width: 288px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It is centered, alright, but I don't have that box around div when I am inspecting element in Chrome, and my div shows at top of the page on chrome, inside inspected element.
If I float it left than I will get that box, but centered with margin, no.

How to fix this?

Comment: What is html? Post html too.

Comment: define a min-height and check

Comment: Please add html aswell

Comment: is it `.div` or `div`?

Comment: there is no way to copy all website css, no one would look at that. mr_green it is .div as class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this kind

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center-div {
  display: block;
  width: 288px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"  >
  <div class="center-div"></div>
</div>
```